# SSL Loading external images

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application that is using SSL. Is there anyway to load external images without the SSL warning dialog? Perhaps suppress this warning or can anyone suggest a better way to load external?

Thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

First way, and simple if possible, is host the images behind the SSL. As they're external I can see how this might not be possible.

Second way, and requires more work. Create a page that sits behind your SSL that you can call instead of calling the images directly and have this page read the images and return as an image in the response. Unless the images are from a trusted source I would probably try and avoid this. This also will create more overhead in reading and returning the image, you probably want to cache the images at least.

If possible I'd go with the first way and stick your images so they're behind the SSL.